# EF4 update navigation property An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: entity-framework-4, navigation

I am trying to implement a let's say "change my account email address" fonctionality.

I want to keep backup of all user emails in (R_EmailAddressHistory table).

Here are some of my project's code.

```
public bool ChangeEmailAddress(string username, string newEmailAddress,  string callbackUrl)
{
    DateTime currentUtcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

    R_User currentUser = UserRepo.GetSingle(whereCondition: w=>w.Username == username);
    currentUser.UpdateDate = currentUtcTime;

    if (currentUser.HasPendingNewEmail)
    {
        R_EmailAddressHistory currentPendingRequest = EmailHistoRepo.GetSingle(whereCondition: w => w.StatusID == (int)Reno.Common.Enums.RecordStatus.Pending && w.R_User.GId == currentUser.GId);
        currentPendingRequest.NewEmail = newEmailAddress;
        currentPendingRequest.UpdateDate = currentUtcTime;

        EmailHistoRepo.Update(currentPendingRequest);
    }
    else
    {
        currentUser.HasPendingNewEmail = true;

        R_EmailAddressHistory newEmail = new R_EmailAddressHistory();
        newEmail.UserId = currentUser.GId;
        newEmail.R_User = currentUser;
        newEmail.NewEmail = newEmailAddress;
        newEmail.InsertDate = currentUtcTime;
        newEmail.StatusID = (int) Reno.Common.Enums.RecordStatus.Pending;
        currentUser.R_EmailAddressHistory.Add(newEmail);
    }

    IdentityResult idtResult = UserRepo.Update(currentUser);

    if(idtResult == IdentityResult.Succeeded)
    {
        //Send notification to current email address for validation before proceeding change email process
        bool sendResult = Communication.EmailService.SendChangeEmailValidation(username,currentUser.Email, newEmailAddress, callbackUrl);
        return sendResult;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The previous method is use to change an email address. Each of my tables (R_User and EmailAddressHistory ) has Repository (UserRepo and EmailHistoRepo). The implement the same IRepositoryBase class, here is the Update methode

```
public IdentityResult Update(T entity)
{
    try
    {
        if (_currentContext.DbContext.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            _currentContext.DbContext.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
        }

        _currentContext.DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

        return IdentityResult.Succeeded;
    }
    catch
    {
        return IdentityResult.Failed;
    }
}
```

When a user has already a non validate new email address, when he request to change his current email address, I show him the pending new email address and he can change it, in this case I whant to update my historical table instead of creating a new one, cause only one pending new email address is allow. In such a case, my code failed in the line EmailHistoRepo.Update(currentPendingRequest) throwing the error :  **An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.**

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

**EDIT**

I am using MVC(4) with a unitOfWork. My UOW is initialized in a the Controller the first time the DB is queried and the Commit is done in the global.asax file in Appalication_EndRequest (see below).

```
        protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CommitChanges();
    }

    private void CommitChanges()
    {
        Reno.BLL.Services.Singleton.UnitOfWork unitOfWork = Reno.BLL.Services.Singleton.UnitOfWork.GetCurrentInstance(false);
        if (unitOfWork != null)
        {
            unitOfWork.Commit();
            unitOfWork.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Comment: SIde note: A repository shouldn't return an `IdentityResult`, it shouldn't be aware of ASP.Net in any way. (single responsibility principle).

Comment: Thanks Gert, I will make the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. The problem was that when I first get the user in line

```
 R_User currentUser = UserRepo.GetSingle(whereCondition: w=>w.Username == username);
```

The currentUser variable hold a refrence of all of its R_EmailAddressHistory. 
And then after, I queried the DB (2nd time) to get the pending email change request (or type R_EmailAddressHistory) to modify its new email and its update date, in line

```
R_EmailAddressHistory currentPendingRequest = EmailHistoRepo.GetSingle(whereCondition: w => w.StatusID == (int)Reno.Common.Enums.RecordStatus.Pending && w.R_User.GId == currentUser.GId);
            currentPendingRequest.NewEmail = newEmailAddress;
            currentPendingRequest.UpdateDate = currentUtcTime;
```

But te last code updates only currentPendingRequest while another reference of the same object which is in currentUser.R_EmailAddressHistory is not update and was already tracked by the context. Therefore, by doing an update on the new instance (EmailHistoRepo.Update(currentPendingRequest)), the code failed: the same object if referenced in 2 places.

So, the solution was (the only thing I modified):

```
            R_User currentUser = UserRepo.GetSingle(whereCondition: w=>w.Username == username);
        currentUser.UpdateDate = currentUtcTime;

        if (currentUser.HasPendingNewEmail)
        {
            R_EmailAddressHistory currentPendingRequest = currentUser.R_EmailAddressHistory.Where(h => h.StatusID == (int)Reno.Common.Enums.RecordStatus.Pending).First(); // EmailHistoRepo.GetSingle(whereCondition: w => w.StatusID == (int)Reno.Common.Enums.RecordStatus.Pending && w.R_User.GId == currentUser.GId);
            currentPendingRequest.NewEmail = newEmailAddress;
            currentPendingRequest.UpdateDate = currentUtcTime;

        }
```

I decided to modify the instance in currentUser variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your currentUser is modified before updating the emailaddress. Save the changes to currentUser first.

Something like this:

```
R_User currentUser = UserRepo.GetSingle(whereCondition: w=>w.Username == username);
currentUser.UpdateDate = currentUtcTime;

bool pendingNewEmail = currentUser.HasPendingNewEmail;
 UserRepo.Update(currentUser);

if (pendingNewEmail)
{
    R_EmailAddressHistory currentPendingRequest = EmailHistoRepo.GetSingle(whereCondition: w => w.StatusID == (int)Reno.Common.Enums.RecordStatus.Pending && w.R_User.GId == currentUser.GId);
    currentPendingRequest.NewEmail = newEmailAddress;
    currentPendingRequest.UpdateDate = currentUtcTime;

    EmailHistoRepo.Update(currentPendingRequest);
}
else
```

Comment: Hi leondepdelaw,
The problem is actually I'm using MVC (4) with a unitoOfWork patern too. My UOW is initialiaze the first time the database is queried in the controller it is committed on my Application_EndRequest method in the Global.aspx